# ios swift How to add images to navigationbar that are not in the center/titleview?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In swift, how do I add an icon to the navigation bar on the side instead of the middle?
I want to do what Slack does with their search icon by having it appear just next to the right menu icon, see picture here: https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/618783545/1b2dca063c580767bf28c885e22c61bc

I DO NOT want the icon to be in the center of the navigation bar with the title view property, which is what most people do. How do I have the icon appear next to the right menu? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this with Swift yet but this works on Objective-C. You can add multiple items to the right by passing an array of `UIBarButtonItems` to `[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:]`

Comment: This was the idea I was looking for! It does work in Swift, most of the commands and methods carry over. More details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KdRpFEOG9I

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the complexity of your requirements you have 2 options:

1. Create your custom navigation bar (is just a UIView subclass)
2. Create an image ad apply it as a background of the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

you can subclass it and personalize your navigation bar, this tutorial is good for that:
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-navigation-bar-ios8-swift

Comment: ahhh 2011, simpler times back then.